# How do I make my footer background image stretch and be responsive?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design

Currently, my website's footer does not stretch or flex to work with different screen sizes. If the screan is too wide it cuts off. If the screen is too small it also cuts off.

```css
#main-footer {
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Any ideas with how to fix this?

[directiveconsulting.com](http://directiveconsulting.com)

Comment: your code - html? image details? Please specify relevant information, so people can answer better.

Comment: also, look in to `background-size: cover` or `contain` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Okay thanks :) Here is what my css looks like #main-footer {
background-color: #fff;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

Comment: Okay looks great on desktop! How do we fix on mobile?

Comment: If I were you I would make the background of the image white, save it as a jpg (to save space), then make the background-color the same color as the dark teal color. I would then set the background-size as 100% positioned at the top. Otherwise the image starts to look a bit pixelated when stretched so much.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size:cover` will make sure your image always fills the space.
`background-size:contain` will make sure it always fits into the space (possibly leaving gaps uncovered, if the proportions are different. You can also explicitly set the background-size in %s or pixels, if that's appropriate to the design.

Comment: Thanks! It looks good on desktop now, but when screen size decreases the text in the footer rises and is not legible. Is there a way to pull the text down on smaller screen sizes by using css? Or is there another solution for this?

Comment: You could increase the padding in that section - #footer-widgets currently has top-padding of 80px. Inside your mobile media query, you could override that with #footer-widgets { padding-top: 120px } (or however much is appropriate to keep the text on the image).